# What happens inside a conductor when the current faces resistance?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, conductors

According to my book resistance depends on the the number of collisions free electrons suffer in any conducting device. Now insulators have no free electrons so how do they have high resistance like what collisions are taking place here? Am I getting resistance wrong or am I missing a point. Can someone explain this to me theoretically, numerically im aware of ohms law and how conductance and resistance are inversely related but what's the intuition behind it what is resistance as a whole?

Comment: Could you please quote the book that you are using? Usually textbooks say more than what you mention.

Comment: The resistance is not the number of collsions. Please reformulate the question so that it make sense. What actual formula or definition did you use?

Comment: Who says insulators have no free electrons? Everything will have a few free electrons. More if you apply a strong enough electric field.

Comment: I'm guessing you've over-extrapolated from the Drude model of electrical conductivity, as it's the popular one that involves collisions; note that the Drude model is *only* a model and like all models it is not a perfectly accurate (or in this case, even particularly accurate at all) picture of reality.

Comment: @RogerVadim sorry I just figured out how to reply to comments anywayys the book that ive been quoting is concise physics class 10 icse. It is an elementary high school physics book and it mentions in the chapter electricity "the resistance of a conductor depend on the number of collisions suffered  by the elections with the positive ions while moving from one end to the other"

Comment: @nasu im sorry I reviewed my textbook and deduced that my way of framing the question was absolutely wrong. have made the edits.thankyou

Answer (score 5):

The electrical *[resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity)* $\rho$ (a material property, distinct from the [resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance), which is specific to the geometry) is the inverse of the conductivity $\sigma$.

The conductivity is modeled as $\sum_i e_in_i\mu_i$, which sums up terms related to the number $i$ of relevant [charge carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_carrier) (e.g., electrons, holes, ions).

Each term is the product of the charge carrier charge $e$, charge carrier concentration $n$, and charge carrier mobility $\mu$. The [mobility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_mobility) is the speed (specifically, the [drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) obtained from a given driving force (such as an electric field) when encountering drag (such as scattering).

Insulators don't have a vast number of free electrons as metals do, but they do contain mobile charge carriers excited to the [conduction band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_and_conduction_bands), for example, if by nothing else than the surrounding thermal energy.

Does this get at what you're asking about?

Comment: you said insulators contain mobile charge carriers excited to the conduction band. So with a high enough potential difference insulators can conduct electricity?

Comment: Insulators always conduct some amount of electricity; see also [breakdown voltage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakdown_voltage), which is a link from [Insulator (electricity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulator_\(electricity\)).

Answer (score 2):

If you know Ohm's law, you know what resistance is: there is no other definition. How it's captured in a detailed model depends on the situation. The radiation resistance of an antenna has nothing to do with electrons. Free charge carriers can be holes or ions, not just electrons. An insulator has high resistance because it has few free charge carriers to carry a current.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of resistance more as the resistance of current flow. As my resistance becomes very large, less current will flow through my circuit.

You could even think about it with Ohm's law of course. Write it as a function of current vs resistance (I = V/R), if I have a circuit with a set voltage, I could add a resistor and I would get some current flow through my system, but if that resistance would be very large my current would be very low.

So in a insulator it would make sense why there's no free electrons (or barely any) is due to its high resistance of the material to conduct electricity.

You could imagine electrons flowing through a wire but the resistance would make it harder to get through the path. This image makes it very clear to understand.

[image]

Comment: so I can only describe resistance relative to current? like I can describe current as an individual on its own and can know how it is actually measured like the rate at which electrons pass a cross section and such so that allows me to also know how an ammeter measures current but not for resistance? it depends on the material, an innate property of some sort? tho it can be changed across different physical conditions but say they are all constant while dealing with conductors (metals ) and insulators( carbon)

Comment: Pretty much yeah you could measure how voltage changes with current and find that its linear with the slope being linear. You could also find for a light bulb circuit system it would increase the voltage quadratically with current due to temperature. If the temperature is high you would have more resistance meaning less current flow. Just like how we want our computers to be cold (for which we add fans) because we want a good current flow.